# Why does Rails .select alias change attributes to lowercase?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-postgresql

In our controller, we are trying to show a video series, which should return JSON similar to this:

```
{
  id:   1,
  name: "Series Name",
  videos: [
    id:           2,
    name:         "Video Name",
    isInPlaylist: true,
    isFavorite:   false
  ]
}
```

We are adding the isInPlaylist and isInFavorite attributes via another table where we store data if a user has acted upon a video (rated it, favorited it, etc.).

```
videos = series.videos
           .where('videos.is_live = true')
           .joins("some join to user_videos join_table")
            .select(
               'videos.*,
               coalesce(user_videos.rating, 0.0) as user_rating,
               coalesce(user_videos.enqueue, \'false\') as isInPlaylist,
               coalesce(user_videos.favorite, \'false\') as isFavorite'
             )
```

Note that in our select statement those attributes are explicitly aliased as camel-cased values. However when we execute this query, these attributes are returned lower case instead:

```
{
  isinplaylist: true,
  isfavorite:   false
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a Rails behavior, but rather a SQL behavior. Alias's are folded to lower case unless explicitly quoted. For an example, here is the output of a simple query in psql (the Postgres CLI program).

```
=# select created_at as theTimeNow from users limit 5;
         thetimenow         
----------------------------
 2013-03-05 18:45:11.127092
 2013-09-07 16:43:01.349823
 2013-03-05 18:53:35.888306
 2013-09-07 16:53:06.553129
 2013-10-29 00:38:56.909418
(5 rows)


=# select created_at as "theTimeNow" from users limit 5;
         theTimeNow         
----------------------------
 2013-03-05 18:45:11.127092
 2013-09-07 16:43:01.349823
 2013-03-05 18:53:35.888306
 2013-09-07 16:53:06.553129
 2013-10-29 00:38:56.909418
(5 rows)
```

Notice the column name outputs

Comment: Yep, after more research discovered where it was happening in DB. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping the alias in double quotes preserves case-sensitivity.

`.select('foo as Bar')   # => { bar: true }`

`.select('foo as "Bar"') # => { Bar: true }`

The change to lower case is not an issue with the Rails `.select()` method but is enforced by the DB, in our case PostgreSQL, and is a practice called "Folding". Its worth noting that while PSQL will fold to lowercase letters, mySQL will fold to upper case letters.

I would argue however that it should still be included in the Rails API docs
¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

I like you answer. The behaviour you see is rails default. As an alternative and 
a more classic 'rails way' would be to use a json serializing library like [jBuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder#faster-json-backends). It gives you lot more control over your API but your problem would be easy to fix in that using:

```
json.key_format! camelize: :lower
json.first_name 'David'

# => { "firstName": "David" }
```

To use something like this you would alias the columns as `is_in_playlist` format.

Here's a good place to start with jBuilder learning:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder

Good tutorial on more json serializers:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Shaunak. My only concern is that we would have to iterate through loops to use the jBuilder solution as these are heavily nested attributes via join tables. Using as_json includes and aliasing seems cleaner than that IMO. I however did not see anything in rails API's noting that this was an enforced convention, which I would argue is a documentation issue regardless of whether this is a SQL decision or Rails.